# how do i do input validation inside a try and catch block?

Tags: java

i have a program where user can enter their name and stuff. its isnised a big try bracket. then at the end it has a catch when the user enter letters instead of number therell be warning "invalid input" i wanna make it so if its invalid 3x, the program closes

so far i have this. i ommited some of the unnecesarry codes, but the important part is just the try, and do while loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input_option = "1";

    // calling option method
        print_options();
        int attempt= 0;
          boolean authenitcated = false;
do{
            input_option = input.nextLine();

        if (input_option.equals("0")) {

            System.out.println("Enter your first name ");
            String firstnameopt0 = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter your last name ");
            String lastnameopt0 = input.nextLine();

            type.println("Annual Income: " + income);
            type.println("Tax: " + opt0tax);
            myfile.exists();
            type.close();
        }

        else if (input_option.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("Enter your first name ");
            String firstnameopt1 = input.nextLine();


            type.close();
        }

        else if (input_option.equals("2")) {
            System.out.println("Enter your first name ");
            String firstnameopt2 = input.nextLine();


            myfile.exists();
            type.close();
        }

        //extra_options();


    input.close();
     catch(InputMismatchException  exi){
        System.out.println("you must enter a double");
        attempt++;
    }
}while(attempts < 3 && authenticated == false)
    }
```

Comment: You are missing else statement in options select, when for example inputOption will be 4, or 10

Comment: Scanner.nextLine always returns a string. InputMismatchException (IME) will never be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to add an else, at the bottom of your options select part.
- Good practise would be to cast it to int, because user can enter zero with lead space, which is still valid.
- Secondly close the file after the catch in finally block (close all closeable resources)

  ```
    int attempt = 0;
  boolean authenticated = false;
  do {
      input_option = input.nextLine();
      try {
          Integer option = Integer.valueOf(input_option);
          switch (option) {
              case 0:
                  System.out.println("Enter your first name ");
                  String firstnameopt0 = input.nextLine();

                  System.out.println("Enter your last name ");
                  String lastnameopt0 = input.nextLine();
                  break;
              case 1:
                  System.out.println("Enter your first name ");
                  String firstnameopt1 = input.nextLine();
                  break;
              case 2:
                  System.out.println("Enter your first name ");
                  String firstnameopt2 = input.nextLine();
                  break;
              default:
                  attempt++;
                  System.out.println("you must enter a int");
          }

      } catch (Exception ex) {
          System.out.println("you must enter a int");
          attempt++;
      }
  } while (attempt < 3 && authenticated == false);
  ```